# docker: how to do/setup networking container-to-host for udp / snmp

Tags: networking, docker, udp, snmp-trap, docker-for-mac

I'm using docker for mac, and I'm running an snmp server inside a container, to which I usually send GET requests. For send/receive, docker networking works, as it'll forward/inbound to localhost port to the container.

Where this doesn't work is for outbound, i.e. when the container software needs to send to another machine, or in this case, the host (use case: test snmp traps). It's not very clear how can I access the host back, and how/where can the host listen.

Typically I'd like the container server to send the packet to its localhost:162, but for this to be forwarded to an exposed port to the host machine:

```
(container)localhost:162 -> (host)localhost:32778 (p.ex)
```

So that I could `nc -ul 32778` and see the packets arrive.

I'd prefer to set this up with pure docker, docker-compose and the like aren't an option.

Does anyone have experience with this?